# Groovy iterating and updating Map<String,List<String>> values

Tags: collections, groovy, iteration

I have a `Map<String,List<String>> invoiceErrorLines` as below

```
invoiceErrorLines = ['1660277':['Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported', 'Line : 1 MATH ERROR'], 
                '1660278':['Line : 5 Invoice does not foot Reported'], 
                '1660279':['Line : 7 Invoice does not foot Reported'], 
                '1660280':['Line : 9 Invoice does not foot Reported']]
```

Am iterating over the Map and changing the Line numbers of an error message as below but am NOT seeing the updated error messages when am printing the `invoiceErrorLines` map

```
invoiceErrorLines.each{ invNum ->
   invNum.value.each{
      int actualLineNumber = getActualLineNumber(it)
      it.replaceFirst("\\d+", String.valueOf(actualLineNumber))
   }  
}
```

can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just iterating the strings and call `replaceFirst` on them.   This does not change your data.  You rather want to `collect` your data there.  E.g.:

```
invoiceErrorLines = [
    '1660277':['Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported', 'Line : 1 MATH ERROR'], 
    '1660278':['Line : 5 Invoice does not foot Reported'], 
    '1660279':['Line : 7 Invoice does not foot Reported'], 
    '1660280':['Line : 9 Invoice does not foot Reported']
]

println invoiceErrorLines.collectEntries{ k,v -> 
    [k, v.collect{ it.replaceFirst(/\d+/, '1') }] 
}

// Results: =>
[
    1660277: [Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported, Line : 1 MATH ERROR], 
    1660278: [Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported], 
    1660279: [Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported],
    1660280: [Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported]
]
```

Comment: I hardcoded `1` earlier but it can be any integer which comes from `getActualLineNumber()` please see the updated question

Comment: that does not change anything?

Comment: Nope it doesn't change anything

Comment: or  `[k, v*.replaceFirst(/\d+/, '1')]`

Comment: @tim_yates true, but OP needs to run code in the innermost loop for each line (not reflected in answer)

Comment: @cfrick can you help me with this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86159/regex-to-extract-selective-lines